# SSRS report not showing datepicker control in Chrome and Edge

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to make a report with datepicker in SSRS but the control is showing picker in IE not in Chrome and Edge how can i solve the issue i have tried with CSS below

```
input[type=image] {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

input[title="Show / Hide Parameters"] {
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
}
```

but am unable to fix it. Please help me how can i fix this.

Comment: That's the wonder of Microsoft! SSRS only behaves itself in IE! You need VS2014 for Edge support

Comment: Oh! Ok. Thanx for your comment.

Comment: SSRS has better support for other browsers than IE from version 2016 (pdf printing instead of activex etc..)